# How to dereference fields when printing?

Tags: go, printf

http://play.golang.org/p/joEmjQdMaS

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeStruct struct {
    somePointer *somePointer
}
type somePointer struct {
    field string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SomeStruct{&somePointer{"I want to see what is in here"}})
}
```

This prints a memory address like this `{0x10500168}`

Is there a way to make it print:

`{{"I want to see what is in here"}}`

This is mostly for debugging purposes, if I had a struct with 30 pointer fields, I didn't want to have to do a println for each of the 30 fields to see what is in it.

Comment: I suspect there's not any easy way (Println would have to track circular pointers if it could chase pointers like that), you'll have to implement `func (p *SomeStruct) String() string;` for the outer `SomeStuct`

Comment: `fmt.Printf("%+v", SomeStruct{&somePointer{"I want to see what is in here"}})` by using the %+v it prints out all the attributes with their names. If you just do %v it will show only the values

Comment: Actually I might have been wrong, its showing you the value as a memory location because you are passing it by reference `&somePointer{"`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a great package called [go-spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew).  Does exactly what you want.

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

type (
  SomeStruct struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
    Field3 *somePointer
  }
  somePointer struct {
    field string
  }
)

func main() {
  s := SomeStruct{
    Field1: "Yahoo",
    Field2: 500,
    Field3: &somePointer{"I want to see what is in here"},
  }
  spew.Dump(s)

}
```

Will give you this output:

```
(main.SomeStruct) {
 Field1: (string) "Yahoo",
 Field2: (int) 500,
 Field3: (*main.somePointer)(0x2102a7230)({
  field: (string) "I want to see what is in here"
 })
}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this package. Nice!

Comment: This is an incredible library. The exact thing I needed and it was very easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


type SomeTest struct {
    someVal string
}

func (this *SomeTest) String() string {
    return this.someVal
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(&SomeTest{"You can see this now"})
}
```

Anything that provides the `Stringer` [interface](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) will be printed with it's String() method. To implement stringer, you only need to implement `String() string`. To do what you want, you'd have to implement `Stringer` for `SomeStruct` (in your case, dereference `somePointer` and do something with that).

Comment: I was going to answer the same thing, but it turns out that if you wrap the type in an outer struct, it still just prints the pointer: http://play.golang.org/p/6P4ol8SS8o.

Comment: @joshlf13 My suggestion was actually to just to implement String himself to get the behavior he wants. Maybe there's a more elegant solution, but this one definitely works.

Comment: If the downvoter could please explain what he thinks is wrong with this answer? It's certainly not _magical_, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to print a struct that contains a pointer. When you print the struct, it's going to print the values of the types contained - in this case the pointer value of a string pointer.

You can't dereference the string pointer within the struct because then it's no longer accurately described by the struct and you can't dereference the struct because it's not a pointer.

What you can do is dereference the string pointer, but not from within the struct.

```
func main() {
    pointer := SomeStruct{&somePointer{"I want to see what is in here"}}.somePointer
    fmt.Println(*pointer)
}
```

output: `{I want to see what is in here}`

You can also just print the specific value from within the Println:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(SomeStruct{&somePointer{"I want to see what is in here"}}.somePointer)
}
```

output: `&{I want to see what is in here}`

Another thing to try is Printf:

```
func main() {
    structInstance := SomeStruct{&somePointer{"I want to see what is in here"}}
    fmt.Printf("%s",structInstance)
}
```

output: `{%!s(*main.somePointer=&{I want to see what is in here})}`